# ZREMRANGEBYRANK difference between ZREMRANGEBYSCORE

Tags: redis, sortedset

What's the difference between `ZREMRANGEBYRANK` and `ZREMRANGEBYSCORE` ?

Explain it me regarding to following query:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> ZRANGEBYSCORE my 1 10 WITHSCORES
1) "b"
2) "1"
3) "a" 
4) "4"
```

Comment: You ask about two commands and than give an example with a third command. You should edit your question, and explain your question to be more clear.

Comment: @abhishek-kushwaha, Did below answer helped you out ?

Answer (score 4):

Let's Set your `ZSet` first :

```
ZADD myzset 1 "one"
ZADD myzset 2 "two"
ZADD myzset 3 "three"
ZADD myzset 4 "four"
ZADD myzset 5 "five"
ZADD myzset 6 "six"
ZADD myzset 7 "seven"
ZADD myzset 8 "eight"
ZADD myzset 9 "nine"
ZADD myzset 10 "ten"
```

Let's See What you are selecting using below command :

```
127.0.0.1:6379> ZRANGE myzset 0 10 WITHSCORES
 1) "one"
 2) "1"
 3) "two"
 4) "2"
 5) "three"
 6) "3"
 7) "four"
 8) "4"
 9) "five"
10) "5"
11) "six"
12) "6"
13) "seven"
14) "7"
15) "eight"
16) "8"
17) "nine"
18) "9"
19) "ten"
20) "10"
```

> So It will Select All Elements.

**Output** of `ZREMRANGEBYSCORE` :

```
127.0.0.1:6379> ZREMRANGEBYSCORE myzset 5 8 
(integer) 4
127.0.0.1:6379> 
127.0.0.1:6379> ZRANGE myzset 0 10 WITHSCORES
 1) "one"
 2) "1"
 3) "two"
 4) "2"
 5) "three"
 6) "3"
 7) "four"
 8) "4"
 9) "nine"
10) "9"
11) "ten"
12) "10"
```

> So Elements Having Minimum Score 5 to Maximum Score 8 will be removed. Here Removed Element with scores : `5,6,7,8`

**Output** of `ZREMRANGEBYRANK` :

```
127.0.0.1:6379> ZREMRANGEBYRANK myzset 5 8
(integer) 4
127.0.0.1:6379> 
127.0.0.1:6379> ZRANGE myzset 0 10 WITHSCORES
 1) "one"
 2) "1"
 3) "two"
 4) "2"
 5) "three"
 6) "3"
 7) "four"
 8) "4"
 9) "five"
10) "5"
11) "ten"
12) "10"
```

> So Elements Having Minimum Index 5 to Maximum Index 8 will be removed. Here Removed Elements :  `6,7,8,9`, whose index were `5,6,7,8`

As Per [Redis Commands Documentation](https://redis.io/commands/) :

> **ZREMRANGEBYSCORE** key min max
>
> Removes all elements in the sorted set stored at key with a score
>   between min and max (inclusive).
>
> **ZREMRANGEBYRANK** key start stop
>
> Removes all elements in the sorted set stored at key with rank between
>   start and stop. Both start and stop are 0 -based indexes with 0 being
>   the element with the lowest score. These indexes can be negative
>   numbers, where they indicate offsets starting at the element with the
>   highest score. For example: -1 is the element with the highest score,
>   -2 the element with the second highest score and so forth.